# Need a scrollable tomahawk table with fixed header

Tags: java, css, jsf, tomahawk

I have used t:commanSortHeader in my table and i need  that table to have a fixed header and that table should be scrollable. 
suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a certain webbrowser developed by a team in Redmond doesn't support `overflow: scroll;` on the `tbody` element, that's not possible without a heavy CSS injection and maybe a shot of JavaScript. This isn't reliably in short answerable since the succesful working may depend on external factors. [Google has however a lot of examples](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=scrollable+table+fixed+header).

If you're by coincidence using RichFaces as well or are open to adding another component library, then you may find RichFaces useful. It has a ready-made component, the [`rich:scrollableDataTable`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf?c=scrollableDataTable).